# how to change the index page numbers in sequence order in html using perl

Tags: perl

The index page shows in Manuscript

> **Index**
>
> ab ovo 5, 98
>
> Abweichung 56, 78, 1, 38f., 5
>
> Akrostichon 1, 789f., 24, 3f., 45, 985, 788, 45f., 125, 10, 121, 128,
>   413
>
> Allegorese 451, 892, 333, 454, 155
>
> Allegorie 451, 782f., 311, 344–354, 788f., 58, 8, 19, 110, 115, 12

I am using the below script for linking

```
opendir( DIR, "." ) || die "Cant open Input Dir";
@input = readdir(DIR);
my %link;
my $text2;
@inp = grep ( /html$/i, @input );


foreach $file (@inp) {

    $file =~ s/.html//g;
    print "\n$file";
    open( MIN, "$file\.html" ) || die "Cant open $fname merging file";
    my $text;
    { local $/; $text = <MIN>; }

    while ( $text =~ m/ id="y([^"]+)"/gs ) {
        $link{$1} = $file;
    }
}
close(DIR);
opendir( DIR1, "." ) || die "Cant open Input Dir";
@input1 = readdir(DIR1);
@inp1 = grep ( /html$/i, @input1 );
mkdir( Final, 0777 );
foreach $file1 (@inp1) {
    $file1 =~ s/.html//g;
    open( IN, "$file1\.html" ) || die "Cant open $fname merging file";
    open( OUT, ">Final\\$file1\.html" )
        || die "Cant open $fname merging file";
    my $text1;
    { local $/; $text1 = <IN>; }
    print "\n$file1";


    $text1 =~ s/([0-9]+)([A-z]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>$2/g;
    $text1 =~ s/([0-9]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>/g;
    $text1
        =~ s/([0-9]+)&#x2013;([0-9]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>&#x2013;<a href="#page_$2">$2<\/a>/g;


    print OUT $text1;
```

The output is:

```
<p class="primary">Allegorie <a href="#page_451">451</a>, <a href="#page_782">782</a>f., <a href="#page_311">311</a>, <a href="#page_344">344</a>&#x2013;<a href="#page_354">354</a>, <a href="#page_788">788</a>f., <a href="#page_58">58</a>, <a href="#page_8">8</a>, <a href="#page_19">19</a>, <a href="#page_110">110</a>, <a href="#page_115">115</a>, <a href="#page_12">12</a></p>
```

But the client request to change the page number as below.

> **Index**
>
> ab ovo 1, 2
>
> Abweichung 1, 2, 3, 4f., 5
>
> Akrostichon 1, 2f., 3, 4f., 5, 6, 7, 8f., 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
>
> Allegorese 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>
> Allegorie 1, 2f., 3, 4–5, 6f., 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12

The output should be:

```
<p class="primary">Allegorie <a href="#page_451">1</a>, <a href="#page_782">2</a>f., <a href="#page_311">3</a>, <a href="#page_344">4</a>&#x2013;<a href="#page_354">5</a>, <a href="#page_788">6</a>f., <a href="#page_58">7</a>, <a href="#page_8">8</a>, <a href="#page_19">9</a>, <a href="#page_110">10</a>, <a href="#page_115">11</a>, <a href="#page_12">12</a></p>
```

How to change the index page numbers using perl?

Could someone please please help me to solve this?

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: Show us your code. No one is going to write full code for you.

Comment: haye you made any attempts at this at all, if so please show your code. then people can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: yes. now i have given my code

Comment: OK. that's a good step, because it's showing a good faith effort to solve your problem. Can I suggest though - turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and fix those errors firsts. It will sort out a number of the problems present in your code.

Comment: @Sobrique. ya ok. i am beginner to perl. How can i replace the page numbers as sequence number.

Comment: That isn't your own code, is it?

Comment: Hi @Borodin. Only this code is mine `$text1 =~ s/([0-9]+)([A-z]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>$2/g;
    $text1 =~ s/([0-9]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>/g;
    $text1 =~ s/([0-9]+)&#x2013;([0-9]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>&#x2013;<a href="#page_$2">$2<\/a>/g;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, aside from tidying up your code a bit - it looks like your core problem is:

```
<p class="primary">Allegorie <a href="#page_451">1</a>
```

vs.

```
<p class="primary">Allegorie <a href="#page_451">451</a>,
```

I would suggest that the way you can do that is to change your regular expressions:

```
    $text1 =~ s/([0-9]+)([A-z]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>$2/g;
    $text1 =~ s/([0-9]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>/g;
    $text1  =~ s/([0-9]+)&#x2013;([0-9]+)/<a href="#page_$1">$1<\/a>&#x2013;<a href="#page_$2">$2<\/a>/g;
```

Add a count variable:

```
my $count = 1;
```

And then add `$count++` to your regular expression instead of `$1` or `$2`.

Although I'll point out that perhaps backtracking a bit and using a proper HTML parser would be a better approach to take - HTML doesn't parse well with regular expressions.

Also: Please turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. They're really good ways to avoid some of the nastier gotchas in perl programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sobrique. I could not use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. because the script has made folder. could you please provide sample?

Comment: @Dari: I don't see how creating a directory prevents you from having `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of the program

Comment: @Borodin, actually i am running this script through "bat" file. "c:\perl\bin\ script.pl".

Comment: @Dari: Okay, and why can't you put `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of `script.pl`?

Comment: @Borodin i gotta error when i am using this code in top of the script `Bareword "Final" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at fr.pl` line 27

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding why strict and  warnings are good. If the are off. The errors are still there. Bareword is easy to.fix. Use quotes around the string.

Comment: @Dari: That is `use strict` pointing out a bug to you. The directory name should be a *string*, so the call should be `mkdir('Final', 0777)`